# Xcode build failure when running flutter build ios - clang :error: no such file or directory 'grpc'

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods

I updated my Flutter app to 1.20, which was released a few days ago. I'm now unable to build my project, and I'm getting an error:

```
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edmdhzendjdzkwdvoacrpkniznff/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary/Runner
                         clang: error: no such file or directory: 'grpc'
                         Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code
                     
                     
[+44245 ms] "flutter ios" took 1,467,539ms.
[  +24 ms] Encountered error while building for device.
[        ] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      BuildIOSCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:103:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:860:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #12     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #13     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #14     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #15     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #16     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #17     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
           
           
[ +130 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 128ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if all the pubget packages you are using are supporting iOS in their latest releases. Probably thats the reason you are receiving this error.

If you have upgraded flutter then there would definitely be few packages that need to be edited for removal of deprecated variables and use cases.